# Find all lines in a dataframe that matches specific pattern and extract the strings after split

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
LineEntry: [0x0000000002758261-0x0000000002758268): /a/b/c:7921:14
LineEntry: [0x0000000002756945-0x0000000002756960): /f/b/c:6545:10
LineEntry: [0x00000000027562c9-0x00000000027562d0): /k/b/c
LineEntry: [0x00000000027562c9-0x00000000027562d0): /c/d/f
....
....
```

I am interested only in strings that look like the first two entries( i.e 5 strings after before and after colon delimiter) and extract the last two strings before and after last colon ( Ex:7921, 14)

```
After filtering above, the dataframe should like
LineEntry: [0x0000000002758261-0x0000000002758268): /a/b/c:7921:14
LineEntry: [0x0000000002756945-0x0000000002756960): /f/b/c:6545:10
```

I have tried
`res = re.split(":", df ) and use res[3] and res[4]` to extract last 2 strings before and after colon , but I get errors for 3 and 4th type of lines as above.

**Any effective ways of filtering dataframe entries that exactly looks like the first two line entries?**

Comment: Is `LineEntry: [0x0000000002758261-0x0000000002758268): /a/b/c:7921:14` an entry in the first row, first column?  Is it a string?

Comment: When you wrote "5 strings after before and after colon delimiter", do you mean that you want to match `"[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+"`?

Comment: Would you not be having Nan in the last 2 columns for last 2 rows?

Comment: No, the Line Entries aren't columns and just lines. Sorry for not mentioning.

Input data is not a dataframe and mere lines after reading the file

Comment: So when you wrote that "I have a dataframe that looks like..." you actually meant that you don't have a dataframe? Are dataframes involved at any point?

Comment: So you're reading text from a file, and you want to ***do what*** with the lines that match ***some*** pattern, print them?

Comment: And what ***exactly*** is the pattern you want to match? Any line having four colons? Does the line have to have only digits after the last colon?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the example data given is a column in a dataframe and you want to filter for those rows that end with a digit (number). You can use `str.isdigit()` for this, like below:

```
arr = df['your_col_name'].to_list()
[x for x in arr if x[-1].isdigit()] # return just the column values as list
```

Output:

```
['LineEntry: [0x0000000002758261-0x0000000002758268): /a/b/c:7921:14',
 'LineEntry: [0x0000000002756945-0x0000000002756960): /f/b/c:6545:10']
```

If instead, you want to filter the data frame:

```
df = df.reset_index() # this assumes your index is range(0, nrows)
arr = df['your_col_name'].to_list()
filter = [i for i,x in enumerate(arr) if x[-1].isdigit()]
df.iloc[filter,:]
```

Output:

```
                                       your_col_name
0  LineEntry: [0x0000000002758261-0x0000000002758...
1  LineEntry: [0x0000000002756945-0x0000000002756...
```

Another option is to use `re.search(r'\d+$', string)` but this regex does something similar (searches if string ends with a digit)