# Find all lines that match specific format

Tags: python

I have an output of lines that looks like below after reading the command file

```
fp2 = os.popen(command)
data = fp2.read()
fp2.close()

print data

data output:
LineEntry: [0x0000000002758261-0x0000000002758268): /a/b/c:7921:14
LineEntry: [0x0000000002756945-0x0000000002756960): /f/b/c:6545:10
LineEntry: [0x00000000027562c9-0x00000000027562d0): /k/b/c
LineEntry: [0x00000000027562c9-0x00000000027562d0): /c/d/f
....
....
```

I am interested only in strings that look like the first two entries.

```
LineEntry: [0x0000000002758261-0x0000000002758268): /a/b/c:7921:14
LineEntry: [0x0000000002756945-0x0000000002756960): /f/b/c:6545:10
```

I tried

```
k = re.findall(r'[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+', data)
```

But it returns no output.

Any effective ways of filtering lines that exactly looks like the first two line entries?

Comment: Did you ask this question here already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77192151/find-all-lines-in-a-dataframe-that-matches-specific-pattern-and-extract-the-stri/77192202#77192202

Comment: What is the `type(data)`?

Comment: <type 'str'>.  I also tried re.split(":", data ) but that doesnt seem to help my filtering.

Comment: can't we filter on count of ':' ? like, if line.Count(':')>2 => do your stuffs.

Comment: Do you mean lines that start with "LineEntry" and end with a digit?  That's pretty easy, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I got two ideas for this problem.
Filter on count of occurrence of ':'

```
data = "LineEntry: [0x0000000002758261-0x0000000002758268): /a/b/c:7921:14\r\nLineEntry: [0x0000000002756945-0x0000000002756960): /f/b/c:6545:10\r\nLineEntry: [0x00000000027562c9-0x00000000027562d0): /k/b/c\r\nLineEntry: [0x00000000027562c9-0x00000000027562d0): /c/d/f"
lines = list(filter(bool, data.splitlines()))
filteredLines = filter(lambda line: line.count(':')>2, lines)
for line in filteredLines:
    print(line)
```

Using Regex

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you use Python 2.7 or 3.x. Looking at your `print` statement, I assume you are using Python 2.7. However, I will use the `__future__` package in this answer so the answer is valid for both versions.

---

You could use `re.match` and `splitlines()`:

```py
data = "LineEntry: [0x0000000002758261-0x0000000002758268): /a/b/c:7921:14\r\nLineEntry: [0x0000000002756945-0x0000000002756960): /f/b/c:6545:10\r\nLineEntry: [0x00000000027562c9-0x00000000027562d0): /k/b/c\r\nLineEntry: [0x00000000027562c9-0x00000000027562d0): /c/d/f"
```

```py
from __future__ import print_function

lines = [
    line for line in data.splitlines() 
    if re.match(r"[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+", line)
]

print(lines)
```

I am not sure where you read `data` from. However, it looks like it is read from a file (or some sort of a stream). I recommend using the `with` statement.

```py
from __future__ import with_statement, print_function

import re
import io

# with open(r"c:\data.txt", "r") as file:
with io.StringIO(data.decode("unicode-escape")) as stream:

    lines = [
        # line for line in file
        line for line in stream
        if re.match(r"[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+", line)
    ]

    print(lines)
```